# @_functionBuilder problem with initializer when there is less than 2 items

Tags: swift, dsl, swift5, function-builder

I'm trying to setup a small DSL with the Swift 5.1 `@_functionBuilder`, here's my problem, let's say I have a `Section` type containing multiple rows, and I wish to build them the way stacks are built in SwiftUI. Here are my types:

```swift
struct Section {
    var rows : [Row]

    struct Row {
        let label : String
    }
}
```

Here is my function builder, which takes several rows and make them into a section:

```swift
@_functionBuilder
struct SectionBuilder {
    static func buildBlock(_ segments: Section.Row...) -> Section {
        Section(rows: segments)
    }
}
```

And the extension of my `Section` type to build a section with my function builder:

```swift
extension Section {
    init(@SectionBuilder _ content: () -> Section) {
        self = content()
    }
}
```

This way I can build my section DSL-like:

```swift
let section2 = Section {
    Section.Row(label: "first")
    Section.Row(label: "second")
}
```

And it works perfectly well, except when I want to have only one row, or none:

```swift
let section1 = Section {
    Section.Row(label: "alone") // Cannot convert value of type 'Section.Row' to closure result type 'Section'
}

let section0 = Section { } // Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '() -> Section'
```

But the strangest is that when I do exactly the same without using the initializer, it works perfectly:

```swift
@SectionBuilder
func getSection0() -> Section {
}

@SectionBuilder
func getSection1() -> Section {
    Section.Row(label: "alone")
}

@SectionBuilder
func getSection2() -> Section {
    Section.Row(label: "first")
    Section.Row(label: "second")
}
```

So, if someone can explain what I'm doing wrong, I'm all ears!
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I've also tried by adding those two methods in `SectionBuilder`, but it doesn't help...

```swift
static func buildBlock(_ segment: Section.Row) -> Section {
    Section(rows: [segment])
}

static func buildBlock() -> Section {
    Section(rows: [])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a partial but usable answer!

For the single row section I just have to add this initializer:

```swift
extension Section {
    init(@SectionBuilder _ content: () -> Row) {
        self.init(rows: [content()])
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work when I have no row with this one:

```swift
extension Section {
    init(@SectionBuilder _ content: () -> Void) {
        self.init(rows: [])
    }
}

let section0 = Section { } // Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Section' with an argument list of type '(@escaping () -> ())'
```

So I tried with an escaping closure:

```swift
extension Section {
    init(@SectionBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.init(rows: [])
    }
}

let section0 = Section { } // Expression type 'Section' is ambiguous without more context
```

So, as it is merely for syntactic sugar that I use this DSL notation, I can go with:

```swift
extension Section {
    init() {
        self.init(rows: [])
    }
}

let section0 = Section()
```